# MySql Statement History with user balance algorithm

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, subquery, window-functions

I have a table with payment history

payments:

| id | consumer_id | amount | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 30 | 2021-05-11 13:01:36 |
| 2 | 1 | -10 | 2021-05-12 14:01:36 |
| 3 | 1 | -2.50 | 2021-05-13 13:01:36 |
| 4 | 1 | -4.50 | 2021-05-14 13:01:36 |
| 5 | 1 | 20 | 2021-05-15 13:01:36 |

In final result need to get consumer **balance** after each transaction.
So something like this

| id | consumer_id | amount | created_at | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 30 | 2021-05-11 13:01:36 | *30.00* |
| 2 | 1 | -10 | 2021-05-12 14:01:36 | *20.00* |
| 3 | 1 | -2.50 | 2021-05-13 13:01:36 | *17.50* |
| 4 | 1 | -4.50 | 2021-05-14 13:01:36 | *13.00* |
| 5 | 1 | 20 | 2021-05-15 13:01:36 | *33.00* |

I using this query

```
SET @balanceTotal = 0;
select amount, created_at, consumer_id, @balanceTotal := @balanceTotal + amount as balance
from payments
where consumer_id = 1
```

This works fine until I try to add some sorting or pagination.

Any suggestion on how to write a query with `order by desc`, `limit`, and `offset` to count balance properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a window sum. In MySQL 8.0:

```
select p.*, 
    sum(amount) over(partition by consumer_id order by created_at) balance
from payments p
```

You  can add the filtering on the customer in the `where` clause if you like (in which case the `partition by` clause is not really needed anymore).

In earlier versions of MySQL, an alternative uses a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*, 
    (
        select sum(amount) 
        from payments p1 
        where p1.consumer_id = p.consumer_id and p1.created_at <= p.created_at
    ) balance
from payments p
```

I would not recommend user variables for this; although efficient, their behavior is quite tricky, and their use is deprecated in recent. versions.

Answer (score 1):

If using MySQL >= 8 using a window sum is preferable -

```
select p.*, sum(amount) over(order by created_at) balance
from payments p
where consumer_id = 1
order by created_at desc
limit 0, 5;
```

If you are using MySQL < 8 then using a user variable for this is significantly more efficient than using the suggested correlated subquery. You can have it as a derived table for re-ordering and pagination -

```
select * from (
    select p.*, @balanceTotal := @balanceTotal + amount as balance
    from payments p, (SELECT @balanceTotal := 0) vars
    where consumer_id = 1
    order by created_at
) t
order by created_at desc
limit 0, 5;
```